# Cannot install subkey 3.0

Tags: subkey

I am trying to install subkey, but this command does not work:

```sh
cargo install --force subkey --git https://github.com/paritytech/substrate --version 3.0 --locked
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/master/bin/utils/subkey/Cargo.toml#L3

At the time of writing, the latest version is `2.0.1`. Use that one.

```sh
cargo install --force subkey --git https://github.com/paritytech/substrate --version 2.0.1 --locked
```

More info: https://docs.substrate.io/v3/tools/subkey/

Comment: It is possible to install from cargo now: `cargo install subkey`.

Answer (score 1):

The previous answer does not work any more (at least for me).
You can use this one instead:

```
git clone https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git
cd substrate
git checkout monthly-2021-07
cargo install subkey --path bin/utils/subkey
```

Comment: This is installing a two years old version?

Comment: This is for installing the version 2.0.1 since the previous answer was trying to install that specific version but the provided command does not work any more